# get value from table sapui5 xml

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I have a problem for get value table `sapui5`. I want when click updatebutton, I get row selected index and get value for each column.

This is my code:

```
updateButton : function(evt) {
   var oTable = this.getView().byId("tabelFaktor");
   var iIdx = oTable.getSelectedIndex();
},
```

This is my XML code:

```
<Table id="tabelFaktor"
    selectionChange="handleSelectionChange"
    mode="MultiSelect"
    inset="false"
    items="{
    path: '/',
    sorter: {
    path: 'Name'
    }
    }">
    <columns>
        <Column
            width="12em"
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="TMT FAKTOR" />
        </Column>
        <Column
            minScreenWidth="Tablet"
            demandPopin="true"
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="TAHUN MI" />
        </Column>
        <Column
            minScreenWidth="Tablet"
            demandPopin="true"
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="KODE KELOMPOK" />
        </Column>
        <Column
            minScreenWidth="Tablet"
            demandPopin="true"
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="KODE PRODUK" />
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="MASA IURAN" />
        </Column>
        <Column
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="NILAI" />
        </Column>                 
        <Column
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="NILAI1" />
        </Column>                 
        <Column
            hAlign="Center">
            <Text text="NILAI2" />
        </Column>
    </columns>

    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <ObjectIdentifier
                    text="{tmtFaktor}"/>
                    <Text
                    text="{tahunMI}" />            
                    <Text
                    text="{kodeKelompok}" />  
                    <Text
                    text="{kodeProduk}" />  
                    <Text
                    text="{masaIuran}" />  
                    <Text
                    text="{nilai}" />                       
                    <Text
                    text="{nilai1}" />  
                    <Text
                        text="{nilai2}" />                                                                                                  
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

How to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Regards,
Bobby

Comment: I don't see a button (should it appear in each row, or only in the table header? Also, you have set `mode=MultiSelect` so you would potentially get multiple rows, not 1, which contradicts your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your table is a sap.m.Table you can access the currently selected row / cell values as follow:

```
var selectedItem = oTable.getSelectedItem();
var oCells = selectedItem.getCells();
    var keys = [];
    var values = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < oCells.length; i++) {
        // key = field name in model
        keys.push(oCells[i].getBindingPath("text"));
        // value = field value in model
        values.push(oCells[i].getText());
    }
```

I hope this helps.
Best regards, Sebastian

Comment: Dear Sebastian,

Comment: Dear Sebastian,

Thank you for your reply.

When I try your code, I get the last column value in selected row. How to get all values in each column selected row?

Thank you.

Regards,
Bobby

Comment: Dear Sebastian,

Comment: Dear Sebastian, thank you.. I get the all values in each column for selected row..

Comment: Hi Bobby, I updated the code snippet so that you should get all values in an array. Is your question answered? Br, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

I would not advice looping over cell contents; to follow MVC principles, you should always retrieve the data from the **model**, not from the **UI control**.

Your code will end up a lot more readable as well:

```
var selectedRowdata = oTable.getSelectedContexts()[0].getObject();
```

*(Note: I assumed you have only one selection. If you have multiple selections, do not use `[0]` to get the first (i.e. only one) row, but loop over the array returned by `getSelectedContexts()`)*